# Matplotlib - AttributeError: Unknown property maker

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib

My code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
years = [1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010]
gdp =  [300.2, 543.3, 1075.9, 286.5, 5979.6, 10289.7, 14958.3]
plt.plot(years, gdp, color= 'green', maker='o', linestyle= 'solid')
plt.title("Nominal GDP")
plt.ylabel("Billions of $")
plt.show()
```

I am running this program in Python 3.6.2 but I am getting all sort of error. Below is the error I am getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Python Programs\Python 3.4\test1.py", line 6, in 
>       plt.plot(years, gdp, color= 'green', maker='o', linestyle= 'solid')
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3317, in plot
>       ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py", line 1898, in inner
>       return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 1406, in plot
>       for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 407, in _grab_next_args
>       for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 395, in _plot_args
>       seg = func(x[:, j % ncx], y[:, j % ncy], kw, kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 302, in _makeline
>       seg = mlines.Line2D(x, y, **kw)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 431, in **init**
>       self.update(kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 885, in update
>       for k, v in props.items()]
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 885, in 
>       for k, v in props.items()]
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 878, in _update_property
>       raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
>
> AttributeError: Unknown property maker

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Matplotlib documentation of `pl.plot()`:

> marker: :mod:`A valid marker style <matplotlib.markers>`

So change `maker` to `marker` in your `plot()` call

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Can't believe I didn't see that :)